# Why do I get duplicate keys in dictionaries and in lists in Python?

Tags: python

My problem is, I sometimes get duplicate keys in dictionaries or lists (checking if the item is there beforehand). I couldn't manage to reproduce it with any consistency.

Currently I am saving a list of users accessing my telegram bot in some way like:

```
async def myfunction()
 ..........
     users={}
     if os.access("userlist.json", os.R_OK):
         with open ('userlist.json') as f:
             users=json.load(f)
     currentuser=[str(update.message.from_user.id),update.message.from_user.username,update.message.from_user.first_name,update.message.from_user.last_name,False,1]
     if currentuser[0] in users:
         currentuser[5]+=users[currentuser[0]][5] #counting how many messages the user sent to the bot
     users[currentuser[0]]=currentuser
     with open ('userlist.json','w') as f:
         json.dump(users,f)
........
```

Here's in example of a json dump of a dictionary from the server:

```
{"1033556742": [1033556742, "CatchingStars", "Starcatcher", null, false, 1], "1033556742": [1033556742, "CatchingStars", "Starcatcher", null, false, 1]}
```

Also I have a similar patch of code where I add items to a list in a similar way: I load a list from json, I check if the item is in the list with:

```
if item in list: print ('ok')
else: 
     list.append(item)
     with ('mylist.json','w') as f:
           json.dump(list,f)
```

and I get duplicate items there too, sporadically.

Comment: There's no such thing as duplicate keys in dictionaries, and there's no such thing as keys in lists... Do you mean that things are being overwritten? It's not clear what kind of data you're working with... Please read about how to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The dumps from json in .json files are dictionaries with duplicate keys. 
I know the lists don't have keys, thanks, they have duplicate items, but that shouldn't have been possible cause I only add items when they aren't there.
My problem is exactly that I can't manage to reproduce the bug, if I knew what's essential to reproduce it, I probably wouldn't even need to ask the question.

Comment: Your `if item in list: list.append(item)` only adds items when they **are** already there.

Comment: Thanks, that was a mistake typing it here, it's ok in the code. Fixed and added an actual example of a dictionary dump from json.
Anyway, I think now the problem might be the encoding, with the telegram lib returning the id and texts in random encodings

Comment: Your other code has a syntax error, unmatched `]`. I wonder how many more differences to your actual code are there...

Comment: I accidentally deleted the [ afte currentuser= there when editing, I was a bit confused with the 'code' thing in editing the post. The 1st example is plain copy and paste from my code, I only deleted the prints I have recently inserted hoping to get where the error appears in the logs and deleted this line:
        currentuser[4]=users[currentuser[0]][4]
which is clearly unrelated to the problem.
As I said earlier, I couldn't get the bot to produce double users again and I don't know at what point duplicate items in other dictionaries appeared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can explain your duplicate keys.  It's a quirk of the `json` module.

The issue is that JSON does not support numeric keys.  Keys must always be strings.  You are loading your JSON, which has a string key, then you are adding another entry with the same value as an integer.  Python allows that, as two separate keys, but the JSON module converts it to a string.  Watch:

```
Python 3.8.10 (default, Mar 15 2022, 12:22:08) 
[GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import json
>>> x = {123:'abc', "123":'abc'}
>>> x
{123: 'abc', '123': 'abc'}
>>> json.dumps(x)
'{"123": "abc", "123": "abc"}'
>>>
```

Comment: I'm not convinced this is it. Their `users` is freshly loaded from JSON, so the old key is a string. And their new key `currentuser[0]` is a string as well.

Comment: Actually, that might be the reason, as I didn't use str() at the start. The duplicate in the  list might be an unrelated bug, I'll look into it.

Comment: There's no other reasonable explanation.